# Automapper doesn't fill destination object

Tags: c#, automapper

I use `Automapper` with `CreateMissingTypeMaps` option set to `true`. If I try to fill an existing object of the same type, it doesn't work.

```
class A
{
    public string X { get; set; }
}

var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true);
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var a1 = new A { X = "sample" };
var a2 = new A();
mapper.Map(a1, a2); // a2.X was not set
```

If I create a new object of the same type, it works fine

```
var a3 = mapper.Map<A>(a1); // a3.X is set
```

If I fill an existing object of a different type, it also works

```
class B
{
    public string X { get; set; }
}

var b = new B();
mapper.Map(a1, b); // b.X is set
```

But if I try to fill an existing object of the same type, it doesn't. Is it a bug in `Automapper` or am I missing something?

Comment: It looks like a bug. You might want to create an issue on GitHub.
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues

Comment: Thank you. Added an issue https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2129

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reasons, this is an expected behaviour https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2129. `CreateMissingTypeMaps` is not supported for mapping to the same type. The only way to get it work is to configure the mapping explicitly:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<A, A>());
```